# jQuery UI effect "shake" makes div disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, google-apps-script

I have this div ( that contains the content of my website. I would like to make it shake when something doesn't authenticate properly using the jQuery effect.("shake"). However, I can't get it to shake at all. Instead, the div disappears for a period of time and then reappears. This happens regardless of me switching any of the parameters. The only effect that switching the parameter has is changing the duration of the disappearance.

I haven't been able to troubleshoot much (this is literally my first use of jQuery and the only jQuery I anticipate this project utilizing).

The reason the google apps script tag was added (I added it back) is because this project is using Google Apps Script. I'm using it to pull data from a Google Spreadsheet (which avoids paying for and maintaining a database).

The offending jQuery (is currently in the HTML file):

```
$(document).click(function(){
           $("#container").effect( "shake", {times:4}, 1000 );
        });
```

And here's ALL of the code:

```js
function getTournamentInfo(){
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setTournamentInfo).grabTournamentInfo()
}

function setTournamentInfo(systemData){
  // insert tournament header
   var tournamentBanner = document.createElement("h1");
   var tournamentBannerText = document.createTextNode(systemData[0]);
   tournamentBanner.appendChild(tournamentBannerText);
   document.getElementById("container").insertBefore(tournamentBanner,document.getElementById("maindata"));
   
   //create a space
    document.getElementById("container").insertBefore(document.createElement("br"),document.getElementById("maindata"));
   //insert chamber header
   var chamberBanner = document.createElement("h2");
   var chamberBannerText = document.createTextNode(systemData[1]);
   chamberBanner.appendChild(chamberBannerText);
   document.getElementById("container").insertBefore(chamberBanner,document.getElementById("maindata"));
   
   
   //insert session header
   var sessionNumber = document.getElementById("sessionNameNumber");
   var sessionNumberText = document.createTextNode(systemData[2]);
  sessionNumber.appendChild(sessionNumberText);
}

var ids = [];
var names = [];
var school = [];
function getData(){        
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setIdData).grabDebaters();
}      
function setIdData(systemData){
 for (var i=0; i<systemData[0].length-1; i++)
 {
  ids.push(systemData[0][i]);
  names.push(systemData[1][i]);
  school.push(systemData[2][i]);
  console.log(names[3]);
 }
 makeRows();
}


function makeClassroom()
{
  
}

function makeRows() {
 
 for (var i=0; i<ids.length-1; i++)
 {
  generateDebaters();
 }
 

}
var nameSchoolCounter = 0; // this is used to ensure that all the names are iterated through
function generateDebaters() {
 var mainTable = document.getElementById("maindata");
  
 var debaterRow = mainTable.insertRow(-1);
    debaterRow.setAttribute("onmouseover","darkenRow(this)");
    debaterRow.setAttribute("onmouseout","lightenRow(this)");

 var nameCell = debaterRow.insertCell(0);
 nameCell.innerHTML = names[nameSchoolCounter];
 nameCell.setAttribute("id","debater"); 

 var schoolCell = debaterRow.insertCell(1);
 schoolCell.innerHTML = school[nameSchoolCounter]; 
 schoolCell.setAttribute("id","debater"); 
 nameSchoolCounter++;

 var speech1Cell = debaterRow.insertCell(2);
 speech1Cell.innerHTML = '<input name="Speech 1" placeholder="Enter 1-6">'

 var speech2Cell = debaterRow.insertCell(3);
 speech2Cell.innerHTML = '<input name="Speech 2" placeholder="Enter 1-6">'

 var speech3Cell = debaterRow.insertCell(4);
 speech3Cell.innerHTML = '<input name="Speech 3" placeholder="Enter 1-6">'

 var ethosCell = debaterRow.insertCell(5);
 ethosCell.innerHTML = '<input name="Ethos" placeholder="Enter 1-3">'
    
    var nomCell = debaterRow.insertCell(6);
 nomCell.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="nomBox" name="nom"/>'
    
}

function darkenRow(row) {
   row.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,.6)";
}

function lightenRow(row) {
  row.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
}

function submitProceduresGraphics(){ //  this does all the graphical procedures for submitting
  // this prevents the divs width and height from disappearing (it's set as display: table in the stylesheet)
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var containerStyle = getComputedStyle(container);
  container.style.width = containerStyle.width;
  container.style.height = containerStyle.height;
  
  while (container.firstChild) {
    container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
    }
    return submitProcedures();
}


function submitProcedures(){
  
  //incomplete method
  return students;   
}



//below is what actually runs
getData();
getTournamentInfo();
```

```css
h1{
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 36px;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2{
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#maindata{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 0px;
 width: 70%;
    margin-top: 40px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#maindata td{
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 4px;
    border: 0px;
    border-image-width: 0px;
}
#maindata td#debater{
 
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 14px;
}

body{
 background: url(https://d3591ee267da5305673fdd35d46a7c93a6509bd1.googledrive.com/host/0B3UFP8Xs5x7WUldKaFZJTjhkbWM);   
 }
 
#container {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
padding-left: 40px;
padding-right: 40px;
display: table;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 6px;
position: relative;
top: 100%;
transform: translateY(20%);
}

input {
background-color: none;
}

#nomBox {
  margin-top: 2.5px;
  margin-bottom: 2.5px;
  width: 18px;
  height:18px;
}

#sessionName {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 26.2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px
}

#sessionNameNumber{
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0px;
  font-size:66px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 4px;

}

/* below here is the CSS for the submit button */



.button {
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: Lato,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 40px;;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  text-transform: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 10%;
  /* auto */
  text-align: center;
  /* DELETE WHEN WIDTH AUTO */
}

.button.green {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #46b98a;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.button.green:hover {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #444444;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import common stylesheet. -->
<?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> <!-- This has a font called Lato because TNR was hurting my eyes. Btw Google Fonts is awesome !-->

    <title>autoTab</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
        <div id=sessionName>SESSION<br><p id="sessionNameNumber"></p></div>
  <!-- Right now, this is brining up an unattractive page when submitted. We should get rid of that: https://mashe.hawksey.info/2014/07/google-sheets-as-a-database-insert-with-apps-script-using-postget-methods-with-ajax-example/ !-->
        <table id="maindata">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>
      Debater Name 
     </td>
     <td>
      School
     </td>
     <td>
      <!-- Noice-->
      Speech 1
     </td>
     <td>
      Speech 2
     </td>
     <td>
      Speech 3
     </td>
     <td>
      Ethos
     </td>
                    <td>
      Nom?
     </td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
       <div class='button green center' onclick="submitProceduresGraphics()">Submit Scores</div>
<p>

</body>
 </html>

<!-- Store data passed to template here, so it is available to the
 imported JavaScript. -->
<script>
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "#hello" ).effect( "bounce", "slow" );
});
</script>
 <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('JavaScript').getContent(); ?>

 <!-- Use a templated HTML printing scriptlet to import JavaScript. -->
```

Comment: Can you include your CSS too..  Your current code works perfectly without styling https://jsfiddle.net/Bhagya/ehkg4d1g/

Comment: Why do you have [[tag:google-apps-script]]?

Comment: removed apps script tag

Comment: Hello Ben Cooper, I have just copied your code into JSfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/w470amys/) and it works fine. can you please provide more information / code?

Comment: Post updated to address concerns. Thanks all! @Bhagya

Comment: @BenCooper Welcome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`top: 100%` applied to `#container` is causing your problems. Removing the style doesn't seem to have any effects, so I removed it.

Explanation: When jQuery UI creates the shake effect, it first wraps your element in a `div.ui-effects-wrapper`, which is a `relative`ly positioned element and copies any position styling (such as `top`) from your element. It then places your element, stripped of its original position styling, inside of this div, and animates a shake by adjusting its `left` CSS property. In your case, you had `top: 100%` applied to your container. When jQuery placed your element inside of its effect-wrapper, the wrapper had both `position: relative` and `top: 100%`, which placed your element, the container, off the bottom edge of the screen, out of view. Play around with setting your container styling to something like `top: 20px` and see the effect this has.

Hope I helped!